# Merge two fields together using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Look at the code below:

```
  $query = "
          SELECT * FROM Question q
            INNER JOIN StudentAnswer sa ON q.QuestionId = sa.QuestionId
            JOIN Answer a ON sa.QuestionId = a.QuestionId  
          WHERE
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."' = '' OR q.SessionId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($sessionid)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($questionno)."' = '' OR q.QuestionNo = '".mysql_real_escape_string($questionno)."')
          AND
            ('".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."' = '' OR sa.StudentId = '".mysql_real_escape_string($studentid)."')
          AND(CorrectAnswer = '1')
          ORDER BY $orderfield ASC";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo "
      <tr>
      <td>{$row['SessionId']}</td>
      <td>{$row['QuestionNo']}</td>
      <td>{$row['QuestionContent']}</td>
      <td>{$row['AnswerContent']}</td>
      <td>{$row['StudentAnswer']}</td>
      <td>{$row['Weight%']}</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>{$row['StudentId']}</td>
      </tr>";
        }
      ?>
```

Each row is a field from my database tables. There are 2 rows I am interested in which are:

```
<td>{$row['AnswerContent']}</td>
          <td>{$row['StudentAnswer']}</td>
```

The Answercontent row is the word answer for the correct answer only which I mentioned in my WHERE clause in the query. But in the truth in the database table the AnswerContent field contains rows where it has word answers for every single answerid.

The studentanswer is an id (studentanswerid) for whichever answer the student has selected. What I want is that for StudentAnswer row I don't want it to show the id numbers e.g 10, 5, 2 but instead I want to show student answer's by words e.g. orange, blue, purple. So what I want to know is how do I merge AnswerContent and StudentAnswer together so that whatever the StudentAnswer is, it shows it by word form from 'StudentAnswer' field and not in id form.

Thank You

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge fields together and display output in php and sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809051/how-to-merge-fields-together-and-display-output-in-php-and-sql)

Comment: Dub? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809051/how-to-merge-fields-together-and-display-output-in-php-and-sql

Comment: You've already asked this, and have gotten a valid answer. Don't repost questions.

Comment: You didn't answer it correctly becuase you did not understand what I meant. I repost question better understanding of question

Comment: Don't repost questions - instead edit your original question making it clearer.

Comment: Yeah but then there will be hardly any views if question is editted. While new question means more views because it is a new question

Comment: So what you're saying is you're not following the rules because you want to game the system?

Comment: Well are you going to view a question I posted 1hr 30 mins ago. Probably not so what is point of me editing a question for no one to see.

Answer (score 0):

Do not `SELECT * FROM table`.  Get only the fields you want.  Selecting all the columns regardless reduces maintainability and increases load on your database server.

If you do not like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809051/how-to-merge-fields-together-and-display-output-in-php-and-sql/7809100#7809100), you could always just perform a second query in your `while` loop where you grab the text content for the answer that matches `StudentAnswer`.  That, however, will not be as efficient as the answer to your previous question.

Without any precise definitions of your schema, it's a little harder to write an actual query tailored to your problem.

Comment: The tables are already joined. AnswerContent is in Answer table and StudentAnswer is in studentAnswer table.

Comment: I see, misunderstood the question.